# typescript not reading env file

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables

I am new to typescript and i built this simple mailer application, but the problem is that TypeScript is unable to read the file, when i put it in the src folder it was not copied in dist on build, when i put it outside the src folder and put the manual require just to test IDE did not showed me option for env[image]

and here is my directory tree

[image]

what causes that? i dont have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think node (or typescript) knows how to import a `.env` file natively.

You probably want to install and configure the [`dotenv` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Then you just add this line to the file that boots your server:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

And now your env vars are accessible at:

```
process.ENV.MY_VAR_HERE
```

[Here's a decent article](https://medium.com/chingu/an-introduction-to-environment-variables-and-how-to-use-them-f602f66d15fa) on environment variables and how a `.env` file works with them.

Comment: i did install dotenv but the problem is that .env file is not recognized by typescript (btw i use import) but when i do that in JS it works

Comment: What do you "not recognized by typescript"? When you use the `dotenv` package, you don't import the `.env` file directly. Also, I believe that file names that start with a `.` are omitted from autocompleting imports in most code editors.

Comment: i know it is not imported directly i just wanted to know, if typescript could reach the file because in .config({}) i put "path" property. and if ide omits . from autocomplete why did not tsc copied .env file into build (dist)?

Comment: The whole point of a `.env` file is that those values are provided by the environment at runtime. So it should not ever be in the compiled build. In production those values should be set as proper environment variables in the OS that is hosting your server. The `.env` file is just a way to fake that in a project specific way during development. So I'm still not sure what you're asking, but I don't think it works the way you think does.

Comment: Well, thanks for your response anyway. i was not trying to import .env file in my project i mentioned this whole path thing because i do had problems with configuring path with dotenv, but i tried exact same path as i did in my node projects which was using JS and it worked but it did not in TS so i guess its problem with TS or ES6 modules

Comment: What "didn't work" though? Just the autocomplete of the .env filename? I guess I still don't understand what you expect to happen, and what erroneous thing is happening instead.

Comment: Well, not auto completion of course but i was expecting that i would be able load environment variables because i use exact same directory tree in this app that i use in my previous node projects in which configuration worked but here in this TS project it just does not work

Comment: Requiring a `.env` file wouldn't work in javascript either. [See example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zw7rsn?file=index.js)

Comment: I AM NOT REQUIRING ENV FILE I AM REQUIRING DOTENV AND CONFIGURING IT WITH PATH SAME AS I DO IN TS BUT IT WORKS IN JS AND NOT IN TS

Comment: Well that was really not clear since that appears to be what your screenshots were trying to do. So are you calling `require('dotenv').config({ path: '/some/path' })`? Doing that would have no difference in TS vs JS. It would help if you put the exact code in your question that isn't doing what you expect, and explain exactly what result you are getting instead.

Comment: i know its stupid but i have a typo, i needed slash before `../.env` like this `/../.env`